# Tradeogre API authentication help (curl)

Tags: curl

Sorry for the newbie style Q, but curl isn't a strong point.
Tradeogre's API docs say to use 
curl -u '{public}:{private}'
But it always returns a 405

```
curl -u <key>:<secret> https://tradeogre.com/api/v1/account/balance
```

Is the public the key and the private the secret from my API keys?

Is the quotes or curly brackets needed?

I've tried with, without, double quotes, swapped keys around. Nothing seems to work.  Just trying to get it working in bash for now.

Now I have gotten the non authenticated stuff to work just peachy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`405` means `Method not allowed` means you're sending the wrong type of request - in your case you're sending a `GET` request, where it should be a `POST` request according to the documentation.

In your POST body, a field named `currency` with an example value of `BTC` is required.

Therefore your post request would look like:

```
curl -u <key>:<secret> -d "currency=BTC" -X POST https://tradeogre.com/api/v1/account/balance
```

The `GET` endpoint is called `/account/balances` ;)

Comment: Yup that did it.  Thanks.  I did in the interim notice the GET  vs POST. Spoke too soon.  Get a success but not authorized.  But I think I'm on the right track now.